# Take sublist with fixed interval

Tags: list-manipulation

For example:

```
a = Range[20];
a = ArrayReshape[a, {4, 5}]
```

[image: matrix a]

I want to take elements from `a` with interval = 2 :

[image: sublist of a]

`Take[a, {1, -1, 2}]`  fails to do this.

It would be better if it works for 3D or higher-dimensional large matrix.

Comment: `Take[Partition[Range[20], 5], {1, -1, 2}, {1, -1, 2}]` works, tho. Probably more generally: `myTake[list_?ArrayQ] := Take[list, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[{1, -1, 2}, ArrayDepth[list]]]`. (I don't have *Mathematica* on hand for testing.)

Comment: The way I'd do this is `a[[;; ;;2, ;; ;; 2]]`  (look up `Part` and `Span`)

Comment: @2012rcampion  yes, I found it in the basic examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is precisely what `Downsample` is for:

```
a = Range[20];
a = ArrayReshape[a, {4, 5}];
Downsample[a, 2]

(* {{1, 3, 5}, {11, 13, 15}} *)
```

Comment: That's neat: I've learned a new function today! Would it be correct to say, however, that its functionality can be reproduced entirely by the use of Part, like @2012rchampion showed in the comment to the original question? For instance `a[[;; ;; 2, ;; ;; 3]] == Downsample[a, {2, 3} ]`. Actually, using `Part` seems to me slightly more flexible, because different offsets can be specified for each direction (e.g. `a[[ hoff ;; ;; 2, voff ;; ;; 3 ]]`, but maybe I misunderstand `Downsample`. The `Downsample` syntax is more readable than the `Part` specification though.

Comment: @Marc A quick test confirms that `offset` can be a list: `Downsample[Partition[Range[20], 5], {2, 3}, {1, 2}]` gives the expected result.

Comment: @2012rcampion I see. Thanks for checking!