# Select certain items from nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list as follows:

```
lis1={{{a1,b1,c1,d1,e1},{a2,b2,c2,d2,e2}},
{{a3,b3,c3,d3,e3},{a4,b4,c4,d4,e4}}}
```

and would like to delete certain elements from it resp. pick certain elements to get a list as follows

```
lis2= {{{a1,c1,e1},{a2,c2,e2}},
    {{a3,c3,e3},{a4,c4,e4}}}
```

My problem is that the data I would like to select are not in an consecutive order (otherwise I could use the Part function). Does anyone have an hint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually can still use the `Part` function!

If you know the positions explicitly you can try:

```
lis1[[All, All, {1, 3, 5}]]
```

Or, if they follow a regular pattern:

```
lis1[[All, All, 1 ;; 5 ;; 2]]
```

Answer (score 9):

Just learned from [this answer by ciao](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81413/125) that [`Downsample`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Downsample.html) is made for this kind of task:

```
Downsample[#, {1, 2}] & /@ lis1
(* {{{a1, c1, e1}, {a2, c2, e2}}, {{a3, c3, e3}, {a4, c4, e4}}} *)
```

You can also use `Take`, `Drop` and `Extract` to get the same result:

```
Take[#, All, {1, -1, 2}] & /@ lis1
Drop[#, {}, {2, -1, 2}] & /@ lis1
First@Rest@Extract[lis1, {{0}, {;; , ;; , ;; ;; 2}}]
```

You can use arbitrary lists for `Part` specifications with `Part` and `Extract`. For example

```
#[[All, ;; , {1, 4, 5}]] &@lis1  (* or *)
First@Rest@Extract[lis1, {{0}, {All, ;; , {1, 4, 5}}}]
```

both give all rows and columns `1, 4 and 5` in all matrices in `lis1`:

```
(* {{{a1, d1, e1}, {a2, d2, e2}}, {{a3, d3, e3}, {a4, d4, e4}}} *)
```

Comment: That only works for the specific example. OP said: "My problem is that the data I would like to select are not in an consecutive order (otherwise I could use the Part function)."

Comment: @TheToad, i may be wrong, but i thought the quote meant the OP was not aware of the part specifications other than `from;;to` (since `Part` specs can be _any_  list).

Comment: @TheToad Even though the origins of the name change are clear, it will take (me) some time to get used to. Is it planned as permanent?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin It was just for fun, mostly. I came across an image that I really liked and just went along with it :) How long I'll keep it, I don't know, lol. I've always treated online personas as ephemeral and have fun changing things around but I can see how it might be confusing for others, especially when there are some artifacts and other bread crumbs lying around :) I can revert if you'd like me to/find it confusing.

Comment: @TheToad Oh no, by all means keep it as long as you want :). It's fun to everyone. I wasn't really serious.

Answer (score 5):

```
lis1 /. b1|d1|b2|d2|b3|d3|b4|d4->Sequence[]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lis1 = {{{a1, b1, c1, d1, e1}, {a2, b2, c2, d2, e2}}, {{a3, b3, c3, 
    d3, e3}, {a4, b4, c4, d4, e4}}};

MapAt[Nothing, {All, All, {2, 4}}] @ lis1

ReplaceAt[_ :> Nothing, {All, All, {2, 4}}] @ lis1
```

Both give the expected result:

{{{a1, c1, e1}, {a2, c2, e2}}, {{a3, c3, e3}, {a4, c4, e4}}}

`ReplaceAt` was introduced in `V 13.1` and has the advantage that we can use the usual `Condition` syntax. Example:

```
ReplaceAt[lis1, x_ /; SymbolName[x] != "b1" :> Nothing, {All, All, {2, 4}}]
```

{{{a1, b1, c1, e1}, {a2, c2, e2}}, {{a3, c3, e3}, {a4, c4, e4}}}

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `ReplaceAll` and `Span`:

```
(lis1 /. x_?VectorQ :> x[[1 ;; 5 ;; 2]]) === lis2

(*True*)
```

Or using `ReplaceAll` and `Select`:

```
(lis1 /. x_?VectorQ :> Select[x, OddQ[Det@Position[x, #]] &]) === lis2

 (*True*)
```

Thanks to @eldo for showing me the following shorter way:

```
  (lis1 /. x_?VectorQ :> x[[;; ;; 2]]) === lis2

  (*True*)
```

Comment: Or, even shorter, `lis1 /. x_?VectorQ :> x[[;; ;; 2]]` +1

Comment: Thanks, mate! :-)